# How can I convert my music to show up OGG Vorbis tags?

Tags: music, ffmpeg

What command with FFmpeg should I use to ensure that all of my metadata (Currently, most of the Artist tags are ignored) and music will play perfectly on Android? (Preferably using Ogg Vorbis!)

I'm running the latest stable version of CyanogenMod (7.1) but the majority shows up under "Unknown Artist" on my device, but shows them on the computer. I just use Banshee to sync the music, as I'm a linux user (so DoubleTwist is not a solution ;__;)

Comment: What format is it in now?

Comment: Ogg Vorbis, however some of the tags do not show up. The tracks play correctly though

Comment: You should rephrase your question, like: How can I convert music to ogg so that the tags show up in the Android Music App/Player **or** Why do my tags don't show up when playing Ogg files on Android?

Comment: What extension do the problematic files have? `.ogg` or `.oga`?

Answer (score -1):

Ogg is supported by default.

**[Supported Media Formats](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html)**

Comment: Yeah, it's a case of knowing what formats of tagging are supported

Comment: It's clearly not supported. I have the same problem.